# How to load local JavaScript file with JSDOM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am unable to use JSDOM (version 13.0.0) to load scripts from the local filesystem with a relative path.

I have taken a look at the following questions but they do not answer my question:

- [jsdom can't load local html and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081517/jsdom-cant-load-local-html-and-javascript) (I have already followed the `runScripts` and `resources` suggestion there).

File `foo.js`:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom')

var html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="bar.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Test</div>
  </body>
</html>`

global.window = new jsdom.JSDOM(html, { runScripts: "dangerously", resources: "usable" }).window
console.log('foo')
```

File `bar.js`:

```
console.log('bar')
```

Here is the error I get:

```
$ node foo.js
foo
Error: Could not load script: "bar.js"
    at onErrorWrapped (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resources/per-document-resource-loader.js:41:19)
    at Object.check (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resources/resource-queue.js:72:23)
    at request.then.catch.err (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resources/resource-queue.js:124:14)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:240:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:564:3) Error: Tried to fetch invalid URL bar.js
    at ResourceLoader.fetch (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resources/resource-loader.js:84:29)
    at PerDocumentResourceLoader.fetch (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resources/per-document-resource-loader.js:16:42)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._fetchExternalScript (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:92:30)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._eval (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:161:12)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._poppedOffStackOfOpenElements (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:126:10)
    at OpenElementStack.pop (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/htmltodom.js:17:12)
    at Object.endTagInText [as END_TAG_TOKEN] (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/parse5/lib/parser/index.js:2153:20)
    at Parser._processToken (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/parse5/lib/parser/index.js:657:55)
    at Parser._processInputToken (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/parse5/lib/parser/index.js:684:18)
    at Parser._runParsingLoop (/Users/lone/so/node_modules/parse5/lib/parser/index.js:440:18)
```

How can I load a local JavaScript file while using JSDOM?

Answer (score 9):

`JSDOM` doesn't know where to look for that file locally while executing. So running your example you can follow any of this two approaches.

**1st Approach**

You have to wait for the script file to load and execute.

Create a three files `index.html,index.js and test.js` into the same folder.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    abc
    <script src='index.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
document.body.textContent = 123;
```

test.js

```
'use strict';

const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const options = {
  resources: 'usable',
  runScripts: 'dangerously',
};

JSDOM.fromFile('index.html', options).then((dom) => {
  console.log(dom.window.document.body.textContent.trim());

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(dom.window.document.body.textContent.trim());
  }, 5000);
});

 // console output
 // abc
 // 123
```

**2nd Approach**
Set the external scripts base root folder in `JSDOM` env.

js/index.js

```
console.log('load from jsdom');
var loadFromJSDOM = 'load from jsdom';
```

test.js

```
'use strict';
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
JSDOM.env({
        html: "<html><body></body></html>",
        documentRoot: __dirname + '/js',
        scripts: [
            'index.js'
        ]
    }, function (err, window) {
        console.log(window.loadFromJSDOM);
    }
);
```

Read more from these references

https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1867

[jsdom.env: local jquery script doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480854/jsdom-env-local-jquery-script-doesnt-work)

Comment: The 2nd Approach (using "env") does not work. However the first one does.

Comment: In the first approach, replace `setTimeout(..., 5000);` with `dom.window.addEventListerner('load', ...);`, to avoid introducing a pause.

Comment: @BlackMantha, thank you, just not `.addEventListerner`, but `.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2):

Great answer from [front_end_dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320535/front-end-dev). It helped me a lot and I will share how my code works with this solution to be more clear. Maybe will help others.

```js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

import { logDOM } from "@testing-library/dom";
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";

import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../index.html"), "utf8");

let dom;
let container;

jest.dontMock("fs");

function waitForDom() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    dom = new JSDOM(html, {
      runScripts: "dangerously",
      resources: "usable",
      url: `file://${path.resolve(__dirname, "..")}/index.html`,
    });
    dom.window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

beforeAll(() => waitForDom());

beforeEach(() => {
  container = dom.window.document.body;
});

afterEach(() => container = null)

it("should ", () => {
  logDOM(container);
});
```