# How to get variable in xml file using saxonjs and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, jsdom, saxon-js

I have a xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE agent SYSTEM "http://www.someUrl.com">
<myData>
   <service>
      <description>Description</description>
   </service>
   <courier>
      <listener port="55556"
                />
      <mainService
      name="Some Name"
      port="55555"
      />
   </courier>
</myData>
```

and I want to get the value of the listener port variable using nodejs.
According to the docu for SaxonJs [SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!api/xpathEvaluate) is the method I need. It requires a query and a document node object. When I convert my xml file into dom object I get the error message : "Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

```js
const saxonJs = require('saxon-js');
const fs      = require('node:fs');
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

var xmlFile   = fs.readFileSync(xmlFilePath, 'utf8');

var doc = new jsdom.JSDOM(xml);
var xpathQuery  = '//listener/@port';
var result      = saxonJs.XPath.evaluate(xpathQuery, doc);
```

Comment: See https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!api/getResource for loading an XML or JSON file for SaxonJS to then handle it with XPath 3.1 and `SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate`.

Comment: Note that `xml` was never defined in your code. I think you meant `xmlFile`. Minor nitpick but probably worth an [edit].

Answer (score 2):

To give you an example for SaxonJS with Node.js:

```
const SaxonJS = require("saxon-js");

SaxonJS.getResource({ file: 'input-sample.xml', type: 'xml' })
.then(doc => { console.log(SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate('//listener/@port/xs:integer(.)', doc)) });
```

Of course you can also try to select the `@port` attribute node and output its value with e.g.

```
const SaxonJS = require("saxon-js");

SaxonJS.getResource({ file: 'saxon-js-input-sample1.xml', type: 'xml' })
.then(doc => { var port = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate('//listener/@port', doc); if (port !=null) console.log(port.value) });
```

Or in the ESM module world as

```
import SaxonJS from 'saxon-js';

const doc = await SaxonJS.getResource({ file: 'saxon-js-input-sample1.xml', type: 'xml' });

var port = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate('//listener/@port', doc); 

if (port !=null) 
  console.log(port.value);
```

Comment: @ggorlen, I don't want to enter in that debate at all, I saw the question because of the tag for saxon-js and I am just trying to answer how to use SaxonJS with Node.js. It is implementing the current W3C standard XPath 3.1, that is why I use it, and for XSLT 3, obviously, which is also a W3C standard to process/transform XML (and from XSLT 3) JSON. But I am certainly "biased" as an XSLT/XPath geek that favours the expressive, declarative power of XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1 over most DOM stuff (I only more or less remember from the 90s).

Comment: @ggorlen, well, interesting that you are here to learn but really, are you expecting people to teach you in comments to StackOverflow questions and answers about the pros and cons of certain libraries? And you have already made your point about JSDOM based on popularity or download numbers in your own answer, I don't see what you pretend to want to "learn" now by asking in a comments to an answer that is about the way to use SaxonJS, as the question has a tag for that. In the world I live there is no objective "better" applying universally to all people/visitors, personal choice is liberty.

Comment: @MartinHonnen The question clearly shows confusion between Saxon and JSDOM, and if the answers don't attempt to unravel that confusion, they seem incomplete to me. I never said JSDOM is better, only that by virtue of being 100x more popular, it stands to reason that it's the default choice. JSDOM actually seems worse for XPath, but I'm just guessing that since apparently nobody can discuss it. I think I'm going to need to stay away from XPath folks--they seem to be in a different universe. Putting words in my mouth, rollback wars, mod flags, yikes... I'm just trying to answer in the JSDOM tag.

Comment: If there was any confusion as to whether you need JSDOM to use SaxonJS then an answer that solely relies on SaxonJS clearly demonstrates that you can solve that task in the question by only using SaxonJS and clears any confusion, from a technical viewpoint.

Comment: @MartinHonnen It's certainly helpful and your answer is a good one--I looked at Saxon but didn't see an obvious example or I'd have posted it. I didn't realize a working example would appear so quickly, which is why I posted the JSDOM approach. It's possible OP was mainly using JSDOM and thought they had to use Saxon to XPath in it. That said, like I said, it still begs the question of why you'd choose a minor sideline library over a mainstream option? But like I also said, apparently we can't talk about this, so you can forget I asked. I don't want to upset anyone more than I clearly have.

Comment: @ggorian if someone asks for help with a particular technology then it's best to assume that they have a good reason for using that technology, even if the particular problem could be solved with something far less powerful.

Comment: @MichaelKay Feel free to assume what you want; I prefer to write the most useful answer rather than playing into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). A big issue with the thread is that OP left us to guess as we please, without providing any clarification or follow-up. It's not clear to me that JSDOM is totally off-limits here; it's tagged and used, so I don't see a problem with presenting an answer that uses it, then having a brief discussion about when to use which. I'm glad there are alternatives presented with analysis.

Comment: The question asked "how do I use SaxonJS to execute XPath against JSDOM" and the answer is "you can't". So there are clearly a number of ways forward, and none of us is in a position to know which is most appropriate given project constraints we know nothing about. That is precisely the reason why it's best to avoid giving such unsolicited advice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use XPath in particular? Since you have JSDOM, I'd just query using a CSS selector:

```js
import {JSDOM} from "jsdom"; // ^24.0.0

const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE agent SYSTEM "http://www.someUrl.com">
<myData>
   <service>
      <description>Description</description>
   </service>
   <courier>
      <listener port="55556"
                />
      <mainService
      name="Some Name"
      port="55555"
      />
   </courier>
</myData>`;

const dom = new JSDOM(xml, {contentType: "application/xml"});
const {document} = dom.window;
const port = document.querySelector("listener").getAttribute("port");
console.log(port); // => 55556
```

You can use [`JSDOM.fromFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53236877/6243352) to read from disk without using `fs` (although that's fine too).

If you don't mind querying with CSS, Cheerio provides an even cleaner option:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const xml = `...`;
console.log(cheerio.load(xml, {xml: true})("listener").attr("port"));
```

If you really want to use XPath, you can do it in JSDOM (note the `[@port]` change to select by attribute on the `listener` element):

```js
const port = document
  .evaluate(
    "//listener[@port]",
    document,
    null,
    9, // FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE
  )
  .singleNodeValue
  .getAttribute("port");
```

or selecting the attribute string value directly:

```js
const port = document
  .evaluate(
    "//listener/@port",
    document,
    null,
    2, // STRING_TYPE
  )
  .stringValue;
```

Note that using both JSDOM and Saxon is probably unnecessary, since Saxon [can parse the XML without support from JSDOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78182294/6243352). Pick one or the other.

I'm not familiar with Saxon, but at the time of writing, JSDOM has 22,000,000 weekly downloads and 831 questions on SO, while saxon-js has 20,000 weekly downloads and 61 questions on SO. My instinct is to avoid the dependency on saxon-js if possible, since small packages tend to become unmaintained, and are harder to find support for on Stack Overflow and GitHub if you run into problems.

On the other hand, apparently JSDOM XPath has ["quite a few issues"](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3293#issuecomment-977200545), and JSDOM is (probably) a much more complex library, so you may have a good reason for pursuing Saxon if it's a better tool for your particular use case (i.e. you need robust XML support, don't care about the whole DOM API, and don't mind the support/maintenance cost of using a less popular library).

Answer (score 0):

SaxonJS doesn't support all DOM implementations. On the browser it only works with the native browser implementation, in node.js it only works with its own DOM implementation which is xmldom modified with a few bug fixes.

If you want to take advantage of the XPath 3.1 capabilities in SaxonJS, then you need to use the SaxonJS embedded DOM implementation. On the other hand, if you only need XPath 1.0, then most DOM implementations offer this, though not always with a high level of conformance or performance.